# Ionic serve recompiles several times after changes

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, compiler-errors, angular.json

I have an Angular-based Ionic project. The issue is that every time I do changes / save, it recompiles 5-10 times before it settles. It is extremely time consuming for development. I believe it something wrong with my configuration in angular.json, but I just can't figure it out! I would like to only have to reload once on save / changes.

Angular.json:

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "app",
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              },
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "progress": false,
              "watch": false
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:ci"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-build": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit",
    "analytics": false
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

In the console, this repeatedly shows when it recompiles:

````
polyfills.js:12 [webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement disabled, Live Reloading enabled, Progress disabled, Overlay enabled.
login:1  Failed to decode downloaded font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap
login:1  OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 791289956
login:1  Failed to decode downloaded font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap
login:1  OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 791289956
polyfills.js:12  [webpack-dev-server] Warnings while compiling.
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:12
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:21
value @ polyfills.js:7
warnings @ polyfills.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:1
client.onmessage @ polyfills.js:1
polyfills.js:12  [webpack-dev-server] WARNING
10 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-start -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-end -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-sm-start -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-sm-end -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-md-start -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-md-end -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-lg-start -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-lg-end -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-xl-start -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
  :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-xl-end -> subselects_1.subselects[name] is not a function
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:12
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:21
value @ polyfills.js:7
warnings @ polyfills.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:1
client.onmessage @ polyfills.js:1
polyfills.js:12 [webpack-dev-server] App updated. Reloading... ```
````

Comment: does this happen only when you change multiple files at once and then save them? or even with 1 file? if the case is only with multiple files, I doubt it's related to your setting, I'd suggest ctrl+c the previous serve and ionic serve again.
also please test with ng serve as well.

Comment: This happens for single changes, to multiple; It happens when I save and it recompiles.

Comment: This used to happen to me and I fixed it a couple of weeks ago, but I can't quite remember what I did. Are you using the SwUpdate client? I want to say it had something to do with that but I am not certain.

Answer (score 0):

ionic as well as angular, being SPA, when saving they recompile everything to always show you the latest developed version. Some IDEs can block the autobuild on the settings, but if this doesn't cause you major annoyances I would leave the setting, otherwise you would have to remind yourself to rebuild.

Comment: The poster knows that the serve method recompiles on editing files, the problem is that it continually recompiles multiple times even for a single file change.